# How many ways are there to answer 10 questions with given conditions?

Tags: combinatorics

My question is this: there is an exam with 10 questions, they are all true or false questions. With the given two conditions how many ways are there to answer: There are no unanswered questions and no two consecutive problems are answered correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, the exam has already been written and the answer key is already set in stone.  Rather than thinking of sequences of True / False, we should instead consider sequences of Correct ($\color{green}{\checkmark}$) / Incorrect ($\color{red}{\times}$) and count how many sequences of length ten there are with no two (*or more*) corrects in a row.

Consider how many ways there are to have $c$ questions correct and $10-c$ questions incorrect.  To see this, consider placing the $10-c$ incorrects in a line and make a little space between and to the side of each in which we have the option of placing at most one checkmark between, noting that the order of doing so is irrelevant:

$$\underbrace{\underline{~~}~\overbrace{\color{red}{\times}~\underline{~~}~\color{red}{\times}~\underline{~~}~\color{red}{\times}~\underline{~~}~\color{red}{\times}~\underline{~~}~\color{red}{\times}~\underline{~~}~\color{red}{\times}~\underline{~~}~\color{red}{\times}}^{10-c~~\text{spaces for }\color{red}{\times}'s}~\underline{~~}}_{10-c+1~~\text{spaces available for }~\color{green}{\checkmark}'s}$$

Simultaneously pick which spaces happen to be used by our $c$ checkmarks in $\binom{10-c+1}{c}$ and then remove all unused empty spaces, leaving us with a sequence of ten checks or x's where no two checks are next to one another.

Range over all possible values of $c$ to get a final count (*noting that $c$ can range from $0$ to $5$ since if there are $6$ or more correct answers there would necessarily be at least two adjacent*):

$$\sum\limits_{c=0}^5 \binom{10-c+1}{c} = 144$$

---

I encourage you to try thinking about this problem in other ways as well.

Let $f(n)$ count the number of ways you could have such a sequence of corrects/incorrects of length $n$ with no two corrects in a row.  By noting that such a sequence either begins with a correct or doesn't, and if it does begin with a correct it must be followed by an incorrect and then in either case what follows would need to be another valid sequence but shorter, you arrive at the following recurrence relation:

$$f(0)=1$$

$$f(1)=2$$

$$f(n)=f(n-1)+f(n-2)$$

which you should recognize as being the fibonacci sequence with an index shift.  We find that $f(n)=F_{n+2}$ where $F_n$ is the fibonacci sequence.

Indeed, this coincides with what we found earlier, $f(10)=144 = F_{12}$ is the twelvth fibonacci number.